# How do you get rid of duplicates without specifically removing any one value in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I thought this was the answer, but it still leaves the three in there.

```
array.uniq
# => ["0", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "3"]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can pass `uniq` a block, which you can use to convert the items for the purpose of checking uniqueness.

```
array.uniq {|i| i.to_s}
```

Comment: +1 Nice, didn't know you could pass a block to `uniq` like that.

Comment: Yeah, so many of the Enumerable methods take blocks, so when in doubt, I assume there is one.  :-) http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the elements to integers (or strings) for comparison:

```
array.map(&:to_i).uniq
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe u can look up below methods

```
  ruby-1.9.3-p0 :020 > arr = ["0", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "3"]
  => ["0", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "3"] 
  ruby-1.9.3-p0 :021 > arr.map(&:to_i).uniq
  => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
  ruby-1.9.3-p0 :022 > arr.uniq(&:to_i)
  => ["0", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
  ruby-1.9.3-p0 :023 > arr.uniq(&:to_s)
  => ["0", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```